# How to show output when using /bin/zsh -c print?

Tags: zsh

I'm confusing when I use `/bin/zsh -c` with `print` command, there is no output.

How can I get `foo` in next prompt with `/bin/zsh -c`?

```
$ print -z foo
$ foo
(↑this is expected result that foo is in next prompt)

$ /bin/zsh -c print -z foo

$
(not show foo in next prompt)
```

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. Do you want to set the prompt to `foo$`? Then `PS1='foo$ '` is all you need.

Comment: Also, you are starting a new zsh instance. Then print -z foo pushes foo onto the editing buffer stack. Then the shell exits. A child shell does not modify the state/paramters of the parent shell.

Comment: @Jens I'm sorry for my confusing English... What I want to do is inject some strings in next prompt like `$ foo`, not `foo $` only when I execute `print -z foo`.

Comment: The simply run `print -z foo` in the current zsh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because `-z` option prints into editing buffer (for the next prompt). So if you run:

```
$ /bin/zsh -c 'print -z FOO'
```

it will push `FOO` in the next prompt editing buffer of that `/bin/zsh -c` sub-shell. But that sub-shell will exit immediately after running `print -z FOO` and so `FOO` will end up discarded in void. There's no way that subshell can manipulate its parent shell editing buffer (they are completely different processes with their own editing buffers).

If you just want to inject `FOO` to the next command line of current shell just run:

```
$ builtin print -z FOO
```

and the next prompt will look like this (`_` being cursor waiting for user input):

```
$ FOO_
```

Answer (score 0):

Run it in the current shell, instead of in a child.

```
$ print -z echo hello
$ echo hello             <-- Already in the buffer, only pressing ENTER now 
hello
$
```